# How does the $fp and $sp register work in MIPS?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

I am currently reading Computer Organization and Design by John L. Henessy for Architecture course. As far as I understood that $sp points to the most recently allocated address in the stack and $fp points to the begining of the stack. Why exactly do we need $fp? And how does they behave if a procedure calls another procedure? For example when stack grows, the stack pointer decrements, but what are the changes in $fp?

Comment: Cross-site dup: [Frame Pointer Explanation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/194339/98103). It's not what we *need* `$fp` but it helps in many cases like stack unrolling or handwritten asm. Not about MIPS but these could give you some idea [What is the purpose of the EBP frame pointer register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/579262/995714)

Answer (score 4):

`$fp` contains the value of `$sp` just before the current function was called, i.e. the beginning of the current stack frame ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#FRAME-POINTER)). `$fp` is useful for x86 machines where `PUSH` and `POP` are commonly used, and is less useful for MIPS, where `$sp` is typically adjusted once on entry to a function and `$sp` relative addressing can be used.